# Django models problem with foreign keys and relations

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I want to make a model with products that will have a subcategory that will fall into its category.
Here is an example: outerwear (category) -> t-shirt (subcategory) -> White t-shirt with a pattern (product)
But I was faced with the problem that the name of the subcategory is not displayed in the product.

**My models.py**

```
class Global_category(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Имя')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Slug', unique=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['Name']
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

def __str__(self):
    return self.Name

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Имя подкатегории')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Slug', unique=True)
    Global_category = models.ForeignKey(Global_category, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  verbose_name='Имя Категории')

class Meta:
    ordering = ['Name']
    verbose_name = 'Подкатегория'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Подкатегории'


class Product(models.Model):
    Category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

I will be glad to any help

Comment: How do you render such product?

Comment: Just add it to your model SubCategory  def __str__(self):
        return self.name

Comment: try this out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__str__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it to your model SubCategory

```
def __str__(self): 
    return self.name
```

[django.db.models.Model.**str**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__str__)